# Replacement for Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation in .Net 6

Tags: validation, .net-core, migration, .net-6.0, data-modeling

I'm converting an old application from .Net 4x to .Net 6, and I can't seem to find a replacement for Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.  In newer code we've used System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations for similar functionality, but it looks like a lot of the attributes have different names.  Has anyone come across a fix?

Comment: Did you find what you want ?

Comment: I did not.  I ended up writing my own attributes to replace the ones that didn't exist.